# Выдать системное разрешение не системному приложению

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adb

**Задача**

Мне необходимо выдать разрешение `android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS`, которое доступно только системным приложениям, своему приложению, которое НЕ является системным.

**Что пробовалось**

1. Я поместил APK файл приложения по пути `/system/priv-app` (в этой директории лежат системные приложения). В результате приложение получило только некоторые системные разрешения (в которые не входит `android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS`)
2. Выдать разрешение с помощью PackageManager. Я использовал команду `pm grant com.example.myapp android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS`. В результате получил ошибку: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS is not a changeable permission type`

**Решение, которое будет работать, но оно мне не подходит**

Можно подписать приложение системной подписью, и тогда оно автоматически получит все системные разрешения. Мне это решение не подходит, так как я не являюсь разработчиком прошивки, и у меня отсутствует данная подпись. Если вы знаете как можно ее "вытащить", то буду рад услышать совет (есть возможность использовать root или adb).

**Вопрос**

Как выдать разрешение `android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS` моему приложению? Есть возможность использовать root или adb.